# PayPal asynchronous notification

Tags: asynchronous, paypal, notifications

Now information about the successful transaction I get with a redirect the user back to my site from paypal. And then I make additional requests to api paypal.
But if the user cancels the redirect to my site, for some reason, I do not get the information about the transaction.
Is there an asynchronous notification from Paypal for Website Payments Standard or Express Checkout?

Comment: You shold look at Paypal's [IPN service](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)

Comment: I read about the IPN. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/ . But "The notify URL applies only to DoExpressCheckoutPayment".

Comment: I quote: "IPN can send notifications for these transactions:
    Instant payments, **including Express Checkout** and direct credit card payments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) works for all payment methods through PayPal. The Developer.PayPal.com document you linked is a list of variables for the Express Checkout feature and it is telling you that you can only pass the `NOTIFYURL` variable successfully in the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API call.

In Payments Standard transactions you'll use the `notify_url` variable.

You can also just enable IPN within your account to have an IPN post sent to your notification page when any payment completes - regardless of whether or not you define a URL in the button code or API request (the URL you define in the code will always override what is set in your account).